# Is an AJAX request from my own site to my own site a cross-origin request when loaded in an iframe?

Tags: ajax, iframe, cross-domain, facebook-apps, iframe-app

I'm working on a Facebook Canvas App, and which by definition loads the code/webpage for my app in an iFrame on the Facebook website.

During development I have got the impression that if I make an AJAX request from my App's webpage to a webservice for my app which is on exactly the same server/domain name as the webpage, that that is actually technically a cross domain request - because the page originally loaded in the (top) frame of the browser is on a different domain to my webservice.

However I now believe that, due perhaps to a bug in my code, I was mistaken, and a page in an iFrame can make requests to URLs on the same domain as it without being a cross domain requests.

Clarifying this is particularly important to me as I now believe I *can* actually use POST requests instead of having to use JSONP GET requests.

If someone could clarify this for me I would greatly appreciate it. I have search around and cannot find a clear statement on this scenario.

EDIT: To provide more clarification: my Facebook App page URL at https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/ loads my webpage at www.mydomain.com in an iFrame. The webpage at www.mydomain.com  then makes an AJAX request to a webservice on www.mydomain.com (at eg. www.mydomain.com/webservice/). So is the request from my webpage to my webservice a Cross Domain request or not?

Cheers
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document loaded within the iframe is still a document of it’s own, and behaves like any other document, whether it be displayed in a frame or not, when it comes to the same origin policy.

So yes, you can absolutely make AJAX requests to the domain that your document got delivered from, not matter that it is displayed inside an iframe on Facebook.com.

There is no crossing of domain boundaries involved.